Approximating the diameter of a point set
given a set of n points P and a nxn matrix M such that for every two point u,v where M[u,v] is the distance between u and v , and the distance is pseudo metric, is there a property testing algorithem such that given a number D >0 and ε in the range (0, 1) returns the following:

if the diameter of P is D or less, the algorithem returns "yes" with probability at least 2/3
if the diameter of P is more than 2D and we cannot make the diameter of P to become 2D or less by removing εn points in P , the algorithem returns "no" with probability at least 2/3.
in every other situiation , it doesnt matter what the algorithem answers.

i am aware that there is a deterministic algorithem for approximating the diameter by a factor of 2 (The classic 2-approximation algorithm for this problem) that uses running time O(nd), and which is to choose an arbitrary point and then return the maximum distance to another point. The diameter is no smaller than this value and no larger than twice this value.but i cant see a conncection to the given problem .
